# Stata merge with multiple match variables

Tags: merge, stata

I am having difficulty combining datasets for a project.  Our primary dataset is organized by individual judges.  It is an attribute dataset.

```
judge
  j |  x |  y |  z
----|----|----|----
  1 | 2  | 3  |  4
  2 | 5  | 6  |  7
```

The second dataset is a case database.  Each observation is a case and judges can appear in one of three variables.

```
case
case | j1 | j2 | j3 | year
-----|----|----|----|-----
  1  |  1 |  2 |  3 | 2002
  2  |  2 |  3 |  1 | 1997
```

We would like to `merge` the case database into the attribute database, matching by `judge`.  So, for each case that a `judge` appears in `j1`, `j2`, or `j3`, an observation for that case would be added  creating a dataset that looks like below.

```
 combined
  j |  x | y  | z  |  case |  year
 ---|----|----|----|-------|--------
  1 |  2 | 3  | 4  |   1   | 2002
  1 |  2 | 3  | 4  |   2   | 1997
  2 |  5 | 6  | 7  |   1   | 2002
  2 |  5 | 6  | 7  |   2   | 1997
```

My best guess is to use

```
 rename j1 j
 merge 1:m j using case
 rename j j1
 rename j2 j
 merge 1:m j using case
```

However, I am unsure that this will work, especially since the merging dataset has three possible variables that the `j` identification can occur in.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are clear, but even better would be present them as code that would not require engineering edits to remove the scaffolding. See `dataex` from SSC (`ssc inst dataex`).

It's a case of the missing `reshape`, I think.

```
clear 
input   j   x   y   z
  1  2   3    4
  2  5   6    7 
end
save judge 

clear 
input case j1  j2  j3  year
  1    1   2   3  2002
  2    2   3   1  1997
end 

reshape long j , i(case) j(which) 

merge m:1 j using judge 

list

     +-------------------------------------------------------+
     | case   which   j   year   x   y   z            _merge |
     |-------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1       1   1   2002   2   3   4       matched (3) |
  2. |    2       3   1   1997   2   3   4       matched (3) |
  3. |    2       1   2   1997   5   6   7       matched (3) |
  4. |    1       2   2   2002   5   6   7       matched (3) |
  5. |    2       2   3   1997   .   .   .   master only (1) |
     |-------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |    1       3   3   2002   .   .   .   master only (1) |
     +-------------------------------------------------------+

drop if _merge < 3
list 

     +---------------------------------------------------+
     | case   which   j   year   x   y   z        _merge |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    1       1   1   2002   2   3   4   matched (3) |
  2. |    2       3   1   1997   2   3   4   matched (3) |
  3. |    2       1   2   1997   5   6   7   matched (3) |
  4. |    1       2   2   2002   5   6   7   matched (3) |
     +---------------------------------------------------+
```